# get a object value from a json API by Index in a forEach loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, foreach

I am trying to learn how to use `fetch()` APIs this weekend...
and I saw this interesting API service, and I tried to learn how to use this

and I get a little problem, with `javascript`

---

**the problem**

I want to get the data from a `.Json` (and this works fine),

but when I want to put the values in the `<div>` 
and getting by `object[index]` is not showing anything

from what I know it seems possible,

but in this case, is not (...I search everywhere on the internet, no result)

basically... 
this **don't** work     `object[index]; //index variable, is a number`

 this works         `object.object1; //normal method`

---

**what I tried**

yes, I tried the traditional method using `obj1.obj2` 
and is working fine, with the result I want!

> but is not efficient, like I want.

because I want to get the values by `index`

and put the value in the `<div>`

with the `index` of the `NodeListOf<element>`

---

**complete code, I wrote**

> open the snippet to see the code

```js
let orarioText = document.querySelectorAll('.orario');

const fetchPreghieraTime = async() => {
  const data = await fetch('http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=Milano&country=Italy&method=8');
  const orarioJson = await data.json();
  const orario = orarioJson.data.timings;

  orarioText.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.textContent = orario[index];
    console.log(item.textContent + "" + index);
  });
}

fetchPreghieraTime();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tempo-preghiera-container">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <div class="tempo-fajr">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">fajr</div>
      <div class="orario">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
    <!-- 2 -->
    <div class="tempo-duhr">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">duhr</div>
      <div class="orario">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
    <!-- 3 -->
    <div class="tempo-asr">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">asr</div>
      <div class="orario">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
    <!-- 4 -->
    <div class="tempo-maghrib">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">maghrib</div>
      <div class="orario">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
    <!-- 5 -->
    <div class="tempo-isha">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">isha</div>
      <div class="orario">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

---

**What do I mean by efficient?**

1. this is the idea to write less, simpler code:

```js
elementClass.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.textContent = object[index];
});
```

2. you can see how inefficient method below, that is working

```js
elementClass[0].textContent = object.Fajr;
elementClass[1].textContent = object.Dhuhr;
elementClass[2].textContent = object.Asr;
elementClass[3].textContent = object.Maghrib;
elementClass[4].textContent = object.Isha;
```

if you can I want the *less code*, or the simpler solution

( *I don't want you to give a faster program possible, no no, for me if is simple logic that is enough for me* )

(think if I need to write all the name of the object if there is like 50 items, etc..., that is why)

the first Idea is coming to my mind because of *arrays*...

and in arrays, you can use brackets with a number, that start with 0, and that is (is not working)

---

**the problem**

1. code doesn't work

```js
let orarioText = document.querySelectorAll('.orario');
//there are 5 elements with the same class

orarioText.forEach((item, index) => {

    item.textContent = orarioJson.data.timings[index]; 
});
```

2. this is WORKING fine

```js
let orarioText = document.querySelectorAll('.orario');
//there are 5 elements with the same class

orarioText.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.textContent = orarioJson.data.timings.Fajr; //here you see the [index] is replaced by the actual name  
});
```

---

**if you want to try also, here is the API I used**

> here is the API service link, I used
> http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=Milano&country=Italy&method=8

and this is how it looks:

```json
{"code":200,"status":"OK","data":{"timings":{"Fajr":"05:31","Sunrise":"07:19","Dhuhr":"12:37","Asr":"15:26","Sunset":"17:56","Maghrib":"17:56","Isha":"19:26","Imsak":"05:21","Midnight":"00:37"}
```

[image: image of adhan API]

---

**in case, is not clear the problem to you:**

 you can write a comment, asking for more info, I will answer it :)

---

**short summary of what I asked**

I want that this HTML

```html
<!-- 0 -->
<div class="myClass"></div>
<!-- 1 -->
<div class="myClass"></div>
<!-- 2 -->
<div class="myClass"></div>
<!-- 3 -->
<div class="myClass"></div>
<!-- 4 -->
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

to become like this HTML after JS

```html
<!-- 0 -->
<div class="myClass">obj1 value</div>
<!-- 1 -->
<div class="myClass">obj2 value</div>
<!-- 2 -->
<div class="myClass">obj3 value</div>
<!-- 3 -->
<div class="myClass">obj4 value</div>
<!-- 4 -->
<div class="myClass">obj5 value</div>
```

---

I hope there is someone amazing helpful developer,
who have more experience,

 that can help me
(and help also the future developers who see this question)

and thank you all the community!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="tempo-preghiera-container">
      </div>
 </div>

const fetchPreghieraTime = async () => {
  const data = await fetch(
    "http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=Milano&country=Italy&method=8"
  );
  const orarioJson = await data.json();
  const orario = orarioJson.data.timings;

  let orarioText = document.querySelector(".tempo-preghiera-container");

  for (const property in orario) {
    if (property == "Sunset" 
         || property == "Sunrise"
         || property == "Midnight" ) continue;

    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("orario");
    let text = document.createTextNode(property + " - " + orario[property]);
    div.appendChild(text);
    orarioText.appendChild(div);
  }
};

fetchPreghieraTime();
```

output

```
<div class="container">
  div class="tempo-preghiera-container">
      <div class="orario">Fajr - 05:30</div>
     <div class="orario">Dhuhr - 12:37</div>
     <div class="orario">Asr - 15:28</div>
     <div class="orario">Maghrib - 17:57</div>
     <div class="orario">Isha - 19:27</div>
     <div class="orario">Imsak - 05:20</div>
     <div class="orario">Midnight - 00:37</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, @serge, I found this on the internet, and it seems a lot easier `const orarioArray = Object.values(orario);` , basically I changed the JSON to Array, and I get the value from there (with the number variable `index`)

Comment: I tried to answer my own question, and also very thank you for the support and the solution! THANKS! upvoted

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas Your answer is not dynamic too,  you have to create 5 copies of the same  HTML manually, and only  after this you run javascript. It doesn' t make any sense to me.

Comment: yes, you are right! but my real problem was how to access a value by index in JSON... I know I can make this more complex, but for an answer is right to the point. yes, you are right another time, I can `appendChild()`, and `createElement();` but in the answer I wanted to make the most easier to read

Comment: @Serge, I see what you mean with dynamic, but to be honest, you just move the hardcoded configuration from the HTML to the code, and invert the logic. Instead of hardcoded *inclusions* in HTML, you now have hard-coded *exclusions* in your code. Moreover, you potentially *loose* the *order* that was configured in the HTML (in the question) and rely on the order that the response object gives. This happens to be the same, but if the provider ever changes the order, the output will follow, which may not be the intention of the Asker.

Comment: @trincot I am sorry but I am not agree with you.  I have only 1 line  of Html not 5.  And if the weather parameters in Json file are changing from 1 to 100 my code will automatically create 1 or 100 lines of html. Nothing is hardcoded. If developer using your code he will have manually delete or add html according to EACH json file.

Comment: Yes, your code will produce 100 lines of HTML when that happens. I think that is a problem. The server application already included sunset, sunrise, midnight. Later they might add events of the moon, mars, venus and sirius. The Asker clearly wants to have the religious times of prayers and only those.

Comment: @trincot Yes, but if  Sunset in json  will be moved to another place in a list , all code will be broken

Comment: "all code"? Which code? My code will not be broken. Anyway, I don't see any reason to discuss if the Asker is not involved.

Comment: @trincot No, yours is not. this is why I told that your code is more reliable then OP. But my code doesn't depend on the order and property names at all.

Comment: thanks for wanting to help, but don't fight in chat, please. all your code is amazing!

Comment: @Serge sorry for not choosing your answer... at that time I was really a junior just learning new things. Now rewatching your answer you was completely right

Answer (score 1):

You can get the property name that you need from the parent element. It has it in its class name "tempo-....". It just needs one change in the HTML, as you used a different spelling for dhurh. So align that with the spelling in the JSON response.

Here is how you can extract that name from that "tempo" class and then use it to access the timing from the response object:

- Find the parent element with `.parentNode`
- Get the `class` attribute value with `.className`
- Extract the part after "tempo-" using `.match` and the first entry in the returned array
- Convert the first letter to a capital and the rest to lowercase.
- Use it as a dynamic property

```js
let orarioText = document.querySelectorAll('.orario');

const fetchPreghieraTime = async() => {
  const data = await fetch('http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=Milano&country=Italy&method=8');
  const orarioJson = await data.json();
  const orario = orarioJson.data.timings;

  orarioText.forEach((item, index) => {
    let name = item.parentNode.className.match(/(?<=\btempo-)\w+/)[0];
    item.textContent = orario[name[0].toUpperCase() + name.slice(1).toLowerCase()];
  });
}

fetchPreghieraTime();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tempo-preghiera-container">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <div class="tempo-fajr">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">fajr</div>
      <div class="orario">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
    <!-- 2 -->
    <div class="tempo-dhuhr">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">duhr</div>
      <div class="orario">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
    <!-- 3 -->
    <div class="tempo-asr">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">asr</div>
      <div class="orario ">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
    <!-- 4 -->
    <div class="tempo-maghrib">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">maghrib</div>
      <div class="orario">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
    <!-- 5 -->
    <div class="tempo-isha">
      <div class="nome-preghiera">isha</div>
      <div class="orario">error</div>
      <!-- this error text, It will change dinamically with JS -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, @trincot, so in the brackets need to be the name, not the index number. thanks for the information. and getting it dynamically from HTML is a good idea. thank you approved you answer!

Comment: Name match doesn' t have any sense here, since it should be dynamic

Comment: sorry, like he saw @Serge, is not dynamically, and now I found another solution and I will answer my same question... I searched a lot, and I found that you can use `Object.values(orario);` to convert first the JSON to the array, the work with that array with the bracket notation. however you answer is very good

Comment: sorry for this, but thank you for the answer and the solution! sorry and thank thank you for the effort you put into it, you are amazing, upvoted

Comment: I think the whole topic of *dynamic* is over-stressed here, since you want to *filter* the server's response object and potentionally *order* it, so you need configuration for that. You can put that configuration in HTML or in JavaScript. I prefer to keep that in HTML as you did it, as then someone who has no good knowledge of JS can still maintain the HTML and/or CSS part, and influence how it renders.

Comment: this is why I use `<template>` tag, and write the HTML, like it is a component, and copied it with js, dynamically :) in the last answer

Comment: Using a template is a good idea, but you don't cover the filtering and the ordering aspect of the data. Also, your question was about turning a **given** HTML to be populated. I just reread your question and the summary of it, where you say *"I want **this** HTML to become ..."*. So I think I really answered your question.

Comment: @trincot ok, you convinced me, I will re-accept you answer! and thank you, for saying me what I wrong, and help me a lot! thank you really

Comment: I see you removed the acceptance mark half a year later. What happened? Is there a problem with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

> I will answer the same question, so I will help someone in the future :)

---

**short answer**
with `.JSON` format,

❌ you *can't* use the bracket with a *number variable* 
`orario[index]`

✅ inside the brackets, you need to put a string 
(for example `["Fajr"]`, and is like writing `.Fajr`)

and so there isn't any method to access this by JSON!

but... **I found a solution for you!**

like you said also in the question, this method works very well in *arrays*

so we need to do something like this pseudocode:

> **FETCH** -> **JSON** -> **ARRAY** -> **ARRAY[index]**

I saw on the internet that javascript, has this functionality, so you can use it too!

```js
Object.values(orario);
```

more details about: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

so...
I put this in variable called *orarioArray*, so is simple for you!

```js
const orarioArray = Object.values(orario);
```

now what you need is only add this to your `forEach` loop

```js
orarioText.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.textContent = orarioArray[index];
});
```

---

**edited complete code:**

```js
let allTempoContainer = document.querySelector('.all-tempo-container');

let orarioArrayValue;
let orarioArrayName;

const fetchPreghieraTime = async() => {
  const data = await fetch('http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=Milano&country=Italy&method=8');
  const orarioJson = await data.json();

  const orario = orarioJson.data.timings;

  orarioArrayValue = Object.values(orario);
  orarioArrayName = Object.keys(orario);

  for (let index = 0; index < orarioArrayName.length; index++) {
    createOrarioCard(index);
  }
}

function createOrarioCard(index) {
  var OrarioCardTemplate = document.querySelectorAll("template")[0];
  var OrarioCardClone = OrarioCardTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);

  allTempoContainer.appendChild(OrarioCardClone);

  let orarioText = document.querySelectorAll('.orario');
  let preghieraText = document.querySelectorAll('.nome-preghiera');

  preghieraText[index].textContent = orarioArrayName[index];
  orarioText[index].textContent = orarioArrayValue[index];
}

fetchPreghieraTime();
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="all-tempo-container">
    <!-- here it will generate the code -->
  </div>
</div>

<template>
        <div class="orario-container" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
            <div class="nome-preghiera">loading...</div>
            <div class="orario">loading...</div>
        </div>
    </template>

<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

**previus code:**

```js
let orarioText = document.querySelectorAll('.orario');

const fetchPreghieraTime = async() => {
  const data = await fetch('http://api.aladhan.com/v1/timingsByCity?city=Milano&country=Italy&method=8');
  const orarioJson = await data.json();
  const orario = orarioJson.data.timings;

  // JSON to Array
  const orarioArray = Object.values(orario);

  orarioText.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.textContent = orarioArray[index];
  });
}

fetchPreghieraTime();
```

```html
<!-- 0 -->
<div class="orario"></div>
<!-- 1 -->
<div class="orario"></div>
<!-- 2 -->
<div class="orario"></div>
<!-- 3 -->
<div class="orario"></div>
<!-- 4 -->
<div class="orario"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer is not dynamic too,  you have to create 5 copies of the same  HTML manually, and only  after this you run javascript. It doesn' t make any sense to me. There is no difference with @trincot answer

Comment: @Serge sorry, I tried to do my best. and this answer for me, solve all my problems, getting the value in JSON by Index... is something new for me! and really solve my problem :) I know I can delete all HTML, and make more complex the code, but I like to make it KISS Keep It Stupid Simple, but you are 100% right, what you said is true, but for a answer the developer need to see a simple code and find the solution!

Comment: I don't understand this answer: you are not populating with the same times. The last time that is in the result is the time for maghrib, ... so I don't see why this should be correct. I thought your question was to get *specific* times from that JSON, those that relate to the events that interest you (the HTML in your question clearly stipulates which kind of times  you want to display), and this code is not making any attempt to filter and map those to the events and order you have in your HTML.

Comment: @Serge, I think you miss an important point. This is very different from my answer.

Comment: @trincot No much difference for me. It is the same logic, but your code is more reliable then this one, since it works only wnen html exist, OP code will not even notice  if  there is no html

Comment: I still think you miss the point of filtering and ordering, @Serge, but I wont continue a discussion. The Asker will decide what they think is best for them... and I'm sure they'll realise that this answer here will lead to problems, sooner or later, since it just misses important events.

Comment: I completed the code added a few HTML, more js, and all the things are ordered now... is good now? @Serge ... I tried to use `<template>` tag, and use clone node and add dynamically with js... and thank for the efforts and the desire to help to help me and another developers, thanks!

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas, the times are still not correct. Look at the time for maghrib... it is your last output now, and wonder where is the time for isha. By removing your original HTML, you lose the aspect of filtering and ordering, which your dynamic solution does not cover and so the output has a different set of times now than you had in your question.